# Disabling auto-removal of 'rel' attributes in full HTML input format

Tags: wysiwyg

My Drupal 7 site , which is using [Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) with the TinyMCE library, keeps removing the 'rel' attributes. Do you have any idea on how I disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the formatting library from TinyMCE to [Yui](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) as it does not remove the 'rel' tag.